# Android: Getting confused with density per pixel and qualifier on android folders

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution

I have a bit confused with the qualifier. I am dealing with kindle fire 7" and 8.9, galaxy s4.

Kindle Fire 7inch: I need to use values-large-hdpi instead of values-sw600dp in order to work.
Kindle Fire 8.9inch: I can use values-sw600dp not for values-large-hdpi.
Galaxy s4 what qualifier should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the qualifiers refer to what the screen dimensions are. So values-large-hdpi will apply to screens that have a minimum density of hdpi and are classified as a large screen type. The sw600dp means that the in order to use those values the screen must have a minimum width of 600dp. So my guess is that the Kindle Fire 7 inch does not meet the sw600dp requirments (Try holding it in landscape, that might work). But the 8.9 inch (being larger) would meet these requirements. The Galaxy s4 my guess falls into the xhdpi density range, not sure about screen size. Most phones will use normal, but the s4 having such a large screen might qualify to large. I would recommend using a screen width quantifier anyways, as just using hdpi or large is to vague.